# SQL to return rows even if there is no data

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have some students are are awarded grades A to E at the end of the year. I find the percentage of students who have been awarded grades grouped by AssessmentCode using the following SQL.

```
SELECT '2014' as FileYear,
    AssessmentCode, 
    AssessResultsResult as Grade,
    cast(count(*)*100.0/sum(count(*)) over (partition by assessmentcode) as decimal(5,2))as GradePerc
FROM   vStudentReportsSemesterResults
WHERE  (FileYear = 2014) 
   AND (FileSemester = 2) 
   AND (AssessmentCode like '11%') 
   AND (AssessAreaHdgAbbrev2 = 'FinalGrade')

   group by AssessmentCode,
     AssessResultsResult

order by assessmentcode
```

This works perfectly and returns...

```
FileYear  AssessmentCode   Grade   GradePerc
  2014       11CPSIPT        NULL     100
  2014       11CPSSDD        A        11.76
  2014       11CPSSDD        B        47.06
  2014       11CPSSDD        C        41.18
  2014       11DRADRA        NULL     100
  2014       11GEOGEO        A        6.25
  2014       11GEOGEO        B        56.25
  2014       11GEOGEO        C        28.13
  2014       11GEOGEO        D        9.38
  2014       11HISANC        NULL     100
```

Note that some assessment codes have not submitted grades as yet (NULL in the Grade column) and others have submitted grades but there are no students who have been awarded a D or an E, for example.

Is there a way of returning data even if the grades have not been awarded or submitted yet eg

```
FileYear  AssessmentCode   Grade   GradePerc
  2014       11CPSIPT        A        0
  2014       11CPSIPT        B        0
  2014       11CPSIPT        C        0
  2014       11CPSIPT        D        0
  2014       11CPSIPT        E        0
  2014       11CPSSDD        A        11.76
  2014       11CPSSDD        B        47.06
  2014       11CPSSDD        C        41.18
  2014       11CPSSDD        D        0
  2014       11CPSSDD        E        0
  2014       11DRADRA        A        0
  2014       11DRADRA        B        0
  2014       11DRADRA        C        0
  2014       11DRADRA        D        0
  2014       11DRADRA        E        0
  2014       11GEOGEO        A        6.25
  2014       11GEOGEO        B        56.25
  2014       11GEOGEO        C        28.13
  2014       11GEOGEO        D        9.38
  2014       11GEOGEO        E        0
```

I wanted to graph this information and want to know if a Grade has not been awarded etc.

Thanks for any help.

Comment: There are multiple possible approaches, and I'm a bad person for not writing out a proper answer. With that out of the way: try adding [`WITH ROLLUP`](http://technet.microsoft.com/library/ms189305) to your query and see if you can't filter that result down to what you want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to achieve the above result is

```
WITH Results(FileYear,  AssessmentCode   ,Grade,   GradePerc)
AS
(
SELECT 
    '2014' AS FileYear,
    AssessmentCode, 
    AssessResultsResult as Grade,
    CAST(COUNT(*)*100.0/SUM(COUNT(*)) OVER (PARTITION BY assessmentcode) AS DECIMAL(5,2))AS GradePerc
FROM
    vStudentReportsSemesterResults
WHERE  
    (FileYear = 2014) 
    AND 
    (FileSemester = 2) 
    AND 
    (AssessmentCode like '11%') 
    AND 
    (AssessAreaHdgAbbrev2 = 'FinalGrade')
GROUP BY 
    AssessmentCode,
    AssessResultsResult
),
MyGrades(Grade)
AS
(
SELECT
    'A'
UNION ALL
SELECT
    'B'
UNION ALL
SELECT
    'C'
UNION ALL
SELECT
    'D'
UNION ALL
SELECT
    'E'
),
FinalResults(FileYear, AssessmentCode, Grade, GradePerc)
AS
(
    SELECT
        FileYear,
        AssessmentCode,
        CASE WHEN Results.Grade IS NULL THEN MyGrades.Grade ELSE Results.Grade END AS Grade,
        CASE WHEN Results.Grade IS NULL THEN 0 ELSE Results.GradePerc END AS GradePerc
    FROM
        Results 
        LEFT JOIN MyGrades
            ON Results.Grade IS NULL
    UNION ALL
    SELECT
        FileYear,
        AssessmentCode,
        MyGrades.Grade,
        0 AS GradePerc
    FROM
        MyGrades
        LEFT JOIN Results
            ON Results.Grade != MyGrades.Grade
)

SELECT
    FileYear,
    AssessmentCode,
    Grade,
    MAX(GradePerc) AS GradePerc
FROM
    FinalResults
GROUP BY
    FileYear,
    AssessmentCode,
    Grade
ORDER BY 
    AssessmentCode
    ;
```

Comment: Thanks Paul, for your help - works perfectly. I had to get rid of the Order by AssessmentCode statement which it didn't like. Once commented out, it works well.

Comment: Oops - jumped the gun a bit. For subjects with no grades entered, it works fine BUT for those where grades are entered it does the percentages for the entered grades but then does not also add a zero for the grades not entered. For example 11CPSSDD above has no rows for D and E still... Any thoughts?

Comment: Hey Paul, any thoughts on trying to get the above to work correctly?

Comment: Hi Barrelnc, I will modify the query to give the correct results and then I will come back to you.

Comment: Hi Barrelnc, where you able to use the above query ?

Comment: Sorry Paul for taking a little while to get back to you. This works perfectly. Thanks so much for doing all this work. I hope you don't mind - I tried to fix the typo just for accuracy in case others use this - CASR(COUNT(*)*100.0/SUM(COUNT...  to CAST(COUNT(*)*100.0/SUM(COUNT above. I couldn't do it as it wasn't a change of more than 6 characters. Once again - thank you for your help!

Answer (score 0):

If you can manipulate the database objects...

I don't know what your table structure looks like, but I would recommend that you make a table that stores your possible grades (A through E) and make vStudentReportsSemesterResults.AssessResultsResult a foreign-key column.  (Since this looks like a view and not a table, you'd want to do this with the underlying table.)  Now you can outer join to your new table and get results for every value in that table.  As a bonus, if you ever change from "E" to "F" or if the grading system changes, you wouldn't need to adjust the query, since nothing is hard-coded in it.

If you can't manipulate the database objects...

You could make this query part of a stored procedure (or script) and create a temporary table (or local table variable) and join against that.  But the concept is still the same.